# Include @IsOptional values to the body if they are missing with default value

Tags: nestjs

Having following DTO:

```
export class UserLoginRequestDto {
  @IsOptional()
  email: string;

  @IsOptional()
  password: string;
}
```

and passing outside body: `{ email:  'test@gmail.com' }` , how to create pipe that will check keys which are missing from the dto and assign to them null so after pipe, body becomes:

`body: { email: 'test@gmail.com', password: null }`

Current custom pipe:

```
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { instanceToPlain, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class AugmentOptionalPropertiesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { metatype } = metadata;

    if (!metatype) {
      return value;
    }

    // Convert the incoming value to an instance of the DTO
    const dtoInstance = plainToClass(metatype, value);
    // Convert the DTO instance back to a plain object
    const plainObj = instanceToPlain(dtoInstance, { excludeExtraneousValues: false });

    // Assign null to undefined properties
    for (const prop in plainObj) {
      if (plainObj[prop] === undefined) {
        plainObj[prop] = null;
      }
    }

    console.log(Object.entries(metatype.prototype));
    Object.entries(metatype.prototype).forEach(([key, defaultValue]) => {
      if (dtoInstance[key] === undefined) {
        dtoInstance[key] = null; // Or use 'defaultValue' if you want a specific default value
      }
    });

    console.log('plainObj', plainObj);
    return plainObj;
  }
}
```

However i'm not able to find easy way to iterate over the keys from the DTO model it self, any ideas